# How to Switch ON and OFF GPS

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

This question has been asked many a times and i have found many results but none of them really helped me.

Using the below code to Switch ON GPS

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
Log.i("GPS IS ON", "GPS IS ON"+provider.contains("gps"));           

if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled

        Log.i("GPS IS ON", "GPS IS ON");

        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
```

and to switch OFF :

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
```

i am calling these 2 different methods on 2 different clicks.It should automatically switch on the GPS on the device but its not working.

i have even added these permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I have tested these in 4.4 and 4.3 and does on Switch on the GPS automatically.

Also LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED is Deprecated in 4.4 so what is the alternative for that ?

**EDIT**

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();

        try {
            gps_enabled = locManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = locManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        // don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        // if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        // return false;

        if (gps_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, locListener);

        }

        if (gps_enabled) {
            location = locManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        }

        if (network_enabled && location == null) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    0, 0, locListener);

        }

        if (location != null) {

            MyLat = location.getLatitude();
            MyLong = location.getLongitude();
```

}

I have had this code working but seems that if internet is Not there it wont work with GPS turned OFF.

Comment: What is the reason for negative voting ?

Comment: "It should automatically switch on the GPS on the device but its not working" -- that particular security flaw was patched years ago. "i have even added these permissions" -- they have nothing to do with enabling and disabling GPS. "so what is the alternative for that ?" -- hopefully, there is none. Users, not apps, control whether GPS is enabled, for privacy reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for that, i am trying to get the get current location of user(City), using latitude and logititude. how will i get the  values ? do i need internet permission for that as well ?

Comment: "how will i get the values ?" -- use `LocationManager` and `requestLocationUpdates()`. "do i need internet permission for that as well ?" -- you shouldn't.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please see my edit and point me if i am in the right way to achieve.

Comment: "seems that if internet is Not there it wont work with GPS turned OFF" -- sorry, in my previous comment, I assumed that you were looking to work with GPS. If GPS is disabled, and you are using the network provider, the device may need Internet access to find the location. I do not know whether you need the `INTERNET` permission to make that work -- all of my work with locations has been with apps that needed the `INTERNET` permission for other reasons, so I have not tried location access without it.

Answer (score 3):

I think one cannot change the user's personal phone settings(Like GPS turn on-off, sound on-off,display etc.) from any application. It would be security voilation.

In my opinion here only option is to check if GPS is on or off and Redirect User to Settings screen.

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        showPopupToRedirectToSettings();
    }
```

> By using following Intent you can launch settings screen:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.)

Comment: "Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER" -- that has not been true for at least a couple of years. If you only hold `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, attempts to get data from GPS will result in the data being "fuzzed", so it is only about as accurate as a city block.